# How to create a new project from a repository in XCode 4 other then the welcome screen

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4

In the past with XCode 4 I have been creating my new projects from existing repositories using the option provided on the XCode 4 welcome screen "Connect to a Repository".
I want to know how to do this from the XCode menus after the welcome screen is no longer visible and for the speed and convenience.
I tried looking under File->source control but didnt see an option for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new project (and specify whether a Git repository will be created with it), choose File > New > New Project (or press Cmd-Shift-N). Fill out the form and, when you're prompted for a folder in which to save the new project, check the box at the bottom of the sheet that says "Source Control: Create local git repository for this project" before saving.

If you want to create a Git or SVN repository from an existing project that doesn't have one, you'll have to use the command line or your favorite GUI tool, as Xcode's SCM support is still a bit limited. In Git, you can just type "git init /Path/To/Repo" (or "git init" if you're already at that path). SVN is a few more steps, depending on a few choices - easy enough to look up.